# Is there a geometric meaning behind these specific triples?

Tags: it.information-theory

Consider the set of triples $(g_1,g_2,g)\in(\Bbb R^+)^3$ such that $$\log g=(\log g_1)(\log g_2)$$

Is there any geometric or information theoretic meaning behind such triples?

We have $$2\log g=2 (\log g_1)(\log g_2)=(\log(g_1g_2))^2-(\log(g_1))^2-(\log(g_2))^2$$

Comment: Where does the last identity come from? Perhaps some text is missing?

Comment: $(a+b)^2-a^2-b^2=2ab$

Comment: Then please add parentheses somewhere so that it becomes clear that the powers are outside

Comment: It's the saddle $z = xy$ viewed on an exponential scale?

Comment: @NikWeaver i am looking for geometry that comes from information theory like packing or something like that

Comment: This is a super-vague question. What type of "information-theoretic" meaning are you looking for? Which operations are related (source coding, channel coding, etc..)

Comment: @Campello does equation log x =( logy )( logz) have an information theoretic meaning interpretation?